# list item values shows up empty for dialog window

Tags: python, pywinauto

How do we capture the text in below case using Pywinauto

I tried a few methods like .window_text , .children_texts() .get_value under dir for object 'test'

The header value shows up but the list item values shows up empty

```
test=app.MainApp.child_window(title="Feature Properties", control_type="Window").child_window(control_type="Header").wrapper_object()

print(test.children_texts())

test=app.MainApp.child_window(title="Feature Properties", control_type="Window").child_window(control_type="ListItem",found_index=0).wrapper_object()

print(test.children_texts())

test=app.MainApp.child_window(title="Feature Properties", control_type="Window").child_window(control_type="Edit",found_index=0).wrapper_object()

print(test.children_texts())
```

output

```
['Name', 'Value', 'Type']

['', '', '']

[]
```

Specifications

Pywinauto version: 0.6.8

Python version and bitness: 3.8.2

Platform and OS: windows 10

[Dailog window image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRReZ.png)

[UISpy image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrdLs.png)

control_identifiers() for Feature Properties Dialog

[control_identifiers1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrDcG.png)

[control_identifiers2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7KfD.png)

Comment: Can you try method `.get_value()` for an edit box?

Comment: test=app.MainApp.child_window(title="Feature Properties", control_type="Window").child_window(control_type="Edit",found_index=0).wrapper_object()
print(test.get_value()) 

gives attached error 

[![error][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwgI3.png

Comment: Well, no luck. Custom Grid implementation is often a problem.

Comment: I don't know how the UI has been designed. As already been told `get_value` is the code to get UI content. But i don't think it will work as both in UI Spy and control identifier `Name` attribute is empty. With that I don't think, we can get the content. The other way I can suggest is to use OCR. It will be easy to get the content

Comment: @ashtav can you please provide more details on OCR

Comment: OCR is Optical Character Recognition, you can pass on this UI screenshot as input (Image format ) it helps to read the character from the image. Please check `python ocr tesseract`. If your intention is only to get the UI content, you can go with it. But if you have more intent to do on UI automation , I don't think this will be useful

Comment: this is a dev issue
so once the app is updated we can see and capture the values
i will also try OCR if needed
Thanks